# multiple ownCloud android app on the same device - INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error

Tags: android, eclipse, owncloud

I need to install two ownCloud android apps on the same device - suppose CloudA and CloudB (different UI for CloudB). After installing CloudA and running successfully on the device, when I try to install CloudB, Eclipse shows INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error. I tried by changing 'authorities' name in the manifest but it does not work. Any help will be appreciated.